# How to do CFD analysis of coolant flow during turning operation?

Tags: ansys

During turning operation, I want to see at what rate the temperature is increasing at the cutting interface and also to see at what rate the temperature is decreasing after spraying the low temperature and high pressure coolant near the cutting interface.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The community cannot develop the whole project for you. Once you have started on a solution, you can ask a specific question if have problem with your code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be helpful if anyone could provide any suggestion on where and how to start the fluent analysis in ANSYS ?